# Busybox installation on emulator[Error:/system/xbin/busybox: not executable: magic 7F45]

Tags: android-emulator, busybox

I was trying to install busybox on my emulator with the help of section 5.2 in Android Emulator.

My AVD config

Device: Nexus S

Target: Google API(x86 System Image)-API Level 19

CPU/ABI: Intel Atom (x86)

The busybox binary I used is "busybox-x86_64" as my emulator CPU in  is x86.
When I run busybox it throws this error:"/system/bin/sh: /system/xbin/busybox: not executable: magic 7F45"
I tried chmod 777 also but no luck.

Anyone have any suggestions..? Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

You can't run x86_64 binaries on an x86 system, regardless of whether it's real or emulated. You need to install an x86 binary of busybox.

Comment: As i said the binary I'm using is busybox-x86_64

Comment: Yes. x86_64 is wrong. You need busybox-x86.